# Entity relationship

Tags: database

I have doubt in this design([er_lp](http://www.xtupload.com/new/share-E656_49A3F378.html)). My doubt is in how to create many - to- many relationship with entities with composite keys, Secondly, in using date type as  pk. Here each machines work daily for three shifts for different userDepts on one or more fields. So to keep record of working and down hours of machineries I have used shift,taskDay and machinePlate  as pks. As you will see from the ER diagram, I ended up with too many pks in the link table in many places. I hesitate not to get in to trouble in coding phase

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you !!

Dejene

---

See also extra information posted as a second question [Entity Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581933/entity-relationship).  The material, reformatted, is:

> Elaboration: Yes, 'Field ' is referring to areas of land. We have several cane growing fields at different location. It [each field?] is named and has budget.
>
> User is not referring to individual who are working on the machine. They are departments. I used 'isDone' table to link userDept with machine. A machine can be used by several departments and many machines can work for a userDept.
>
> A particular machine can be used for multiple tasks on a given shift. It can work for say 2 hours and can start another task on another field. We have three shifts per day, each of 8 hrs!
>
> If I use Auto increment PK, do you think that other key are important? I don't prefer to use it!
>
> Usually, I use auto increment key alone in a table. How can we create relationship that involves auto increment keys?
>
> Thank you for thoughtful comment!!

---

Answer (score 1):

You always create many-to-many relationships between two tables using a third table, the rows of which contain the columns for the primary key of each table, and the combination of all columns is the primary key of the third table.  The rule doesn't change for tables with composite primary keys.

```
 CREATE TABLE Table1(Col11 ..., Col12 ..., Col1N ...,
                     PRIMARY KEY(Col11, Col12));
 CREATE TABLE Table2(Col21 ..., Col22 ..., Col2N ...,
                     PRIMARY KEY(Col21, Col22));

 CREATE TABLE RelationTable
 (
    Col11 ...,
    Col12 ...,
    FOREIGN KEY (Col11, Col12) REFERENCES Table1,
    Col21 ...,
    Col22 ...,
    FOREIGN KEY (Col21, Col22) REFERENCES Table2,
    PRIMARY KEY (Col11, Col12, Col21, Col22)
 );
```

This works fine.  It does suggest that you should try and keep keys simple whenever possible, but there is absolutely no need to bend over backwards adding auto-increment columns to the referenced tables if they have a natural composite key that is convenient to use.  OTOH, the joins involving the relation table are harder to write if you use a composite keys - I'd think several times about what I'm about if either composite key involved more than two columns, not least because it might indicate problems in the design of the referenced tables.

Looking at the actual ER diagram - the 'er_lp' URL in the question - the 'tbl' prefix seems a trifle unnecessary; the things storing data in a database are always tables, so telling me that with the prefix is ... unnecessary.  The table called 'Machine' seems to be misnamed; it does not so much describe a machine as the duty allocated to a machine on a particular shift.  I'm guessing that the 'Field' table is referring to areas of land, rather than parts of a database.  You have the 'IsDone' table (again, not particularly well named) that identifies the user who worked on a machine for a particular shift and hence for a particular task.  That involves a link between the Machine table (which has a 3-part primary key) and the User table.  It isn't clear whether a particular machine can be used for multiple tasks on a given shift.  It isn't clear whether shift numbers cycle around the day or whether each shift number is unique across days, but the presumption must be that there are, say, three shifts per day, and the shift number and date is needed to identify when something occurred.  Presumably, the Shift table would identify times and other such information.

The three-part primary key on Machine is fine - but it might be better to have two unique identifiers.  One would be the current primary key combination; the other would be an automatically assigned number - auto-increment, serial, sequence or whatever...

---

Addressing the extended information.

It is not clear to me any more what you are seeking to track.  If the 'Machine' table is supposed to track what a given machine was being used for, then you probably need to do some more structuring of the data.  Given that a machine can be used for different tasks on different fields during a single shift, you should think, perhaps, in terms of a MachineTasks table which would identify the (date and) time when the operation started and finished and the type of operation.  For repair operations, you'd store the information in a table describing repairs; for routine operations in a field, you might not need much extra information.  Or maybe that is overkill.

I'm not clear whether particular tasks are performed on behalf of multiple departments, or whether you are simply trying to note that during a single shift a machine might be used by multiple departments, but one department at a time for each task.  If each task is for a separate department, then simply include the department info in the main MachineTasks table as a foreign key field.

If you decide on an auto-increment key, you still need to maintain the uniqueness of the composite key.  This is the biggest mistake I see people making with auto-increment fields.  It isn't quite as simple as "a table with an auto-increment key must also have a second unique constraint on it", but it isn't too far off the mark.

When you use an auto-increment key, you need to retrieve the value assigned when you insert a record into the table; you then use that value in the foreign key columns when you insert other records into the other tables.

You need to read up on database design - I'm not sure what the current good books are as I did most of my learning a decade and more ago, and my books are consequently less likely to be available still.

Answer (score 0):

One good way of not getting into trouble with primary keys is to have a single field for primary key. Usually a numeric (auto incremental) column is just fine. You can still have unique keys with multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

- tblWorksOn
- tblMachine
- tblIsDone

...seem to be the problem tables.

Its looks like you could use **taskDate** for the tblMachine table as the primary key.  The rest can be foriegn keys.

With the changes to the tblMachine table you can then use the taskDate with the fieldNo for the tblWorksOn table and the taskDate with the userID for the tblIsDone. Use these two fields to create Composite Keys (CK)

e.g.

**tblMachine** 
taskDate (PK)

**tblWorksOn**
fieldNo (CK)
taskDate (CK)

**tblIsDone**
userID (CK)
taskDate (CK)